# Slartoolkit Solution Error

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm getting a very strange error in relation to an AR project I'm working on, I am getting a System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SLARToolKit WinPhone.DLL" error in relation to a specific line of code being highlighted, that being:

```
 private static Marker LoadFromResource(string relativePath, int segmentsX, int segmentsY, double width, System.Reflection.Assembly assembly)
  {
     var asmName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(assembly.FullName).Name;
     using (var markerStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(asmName + ";component/" + relativePath, UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
     {
        return Load(markerStream, segmentsX, segmentsY, width);
     }
  }
```

Specificially this line is being highlighted:

```
using (var markerStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(asmName + ";component/" + relativePath, UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
```

This code is found in a "Marker.cs" file which I'm guessing is part of the SLARToolkit.DLL. Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the file there? Is the path correct? Is the build action for the file set as Resource?

Comment: Oh my, it was as simple as importing the actual marker .pat files into the project and setting it to resources as you stated, you  got my brain into gear after making those suggestions, thank you so much I was at a dead end! How could I not have seen this, it was so simple!